# A problem with uniswap v2 periphery contract, can't make a swap through my own contract using the interfaces

Tags: token, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I have deployed this code on ropsten testnet to test uniswap swaps. I am trying to make swap using function "swap" of my contract with this data path:

```
0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab,0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d, 1000000, 261639093, 0x480c65bF4C96f1087d64677E5b39AaC79825Dade
```

but always get error -  Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

btw AmountOut i am getting through my contract function "getAmountOutMin"
Here is the code of my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router {
  function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path)
    external
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
  
  function swapExactTokensForTokens(
    uint256 amountIn,
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint256 deadline
  ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
  function token0() external view returns (address);
  function token1() external view returns (address);
  function swap(
    uint256 amount0Out,
    uint256 amount1Out,
    address to,
    bytes calldata data
  ) external;
}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
  function getPair(address token0, address token1) external returns (address);
}

contract tokenSwap {

    address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private constant WETH = 0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab;
    
    // mainnet weth address - 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    
    function swap(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn, uint256 _amountOutMin, address _to) external {
      IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);
      IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, _amountIn);
    address[] memory path;
    if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
      path = new address[](2);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = _tokenOut;
    } else {
      path = new address[](3);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = WETH;
      path[2] = _tokenOut;
    }
    IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
    }
    
     function getAmountOutMin(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn) external view returns (uint256) {
        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = WETH;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }
        
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
        return amountOutMins[path.length -1];  
    }  
}
```

Can someone explain me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you make your pool successfully or not?
Steps:
Customize Uniswap
Make Tokens
Import Tokens
Make Pool
Swap